# Gatling data feeder with an increment value

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm looking to create a data feeder which increments an integer from 1 alongside some other values. I have found a way to achieve this using AtomicInteger.
Following code shows how I have implemented it. Is there any other way that I can achieve this for instance using the `Iterator.from(0).map()` approach.

```
  def getUUID = randomUUID().toString
  val ordinal = new AtomicInteger(1)

  val itemAttemptForPost = Iterator.continually {
    Map(
      "usedId" -> getUUID ,
      "ordinal" -> ordinal.getAndIncrement()
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: using `from(1)` for consistency with your `new AtomicInteger(1)`.

```scala
Iterator.from(1).map { i =>
      Map(
      "usedId" -> randomUUID().toString,
      "ordinal" -> i
    )
}
```